# Writing to a CSV file in C

Tags: c, csv

My C program generates this data. I need to place it into a CSV file, so that it can be used by another program. How can I achieve this?

```
Student1 Mark1 Mark2 Mark3 Mark4 Mark5
Student2 Mark1 Mark2 Mark3 Mark4 Mark5
Student3 Mark1 Mark2 Mark3 Mark4 Mark5
Student4 Mark1 Mark2 Mark3 Mark4 Mark5
Student5 Mark1 Mark2 Mark3 Mark4 Mark5
```

Comment: Are typing that text or is it in a file?

Comment: C CSV Parser: http://sourceforge.net/projects/cccsvparser C CSV Writer: http://sourceforge.net/projects/cccsvwriter

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could achieve this through `fprintf`

```
for(i = 0; i < num_of_students; i++)
     fprintf(fptr, "%s,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n", name, mark1, mark2, mark3, mark4, mark5);
```

Comment: isnt that writing to a normal .txt file? Or is it the same for a .csv file?

Comment: The CSV file can be implemented as simple text file. I will modify my example to replace the spaces with commas to make comma separated values, so that when you open the CSV in excel, you will be able to load the data into different columns

Comment: thanks. however, is there a way i can display headings in the top column so the output is like this:

ST_ID   M1 M2 M3 M4 M5 on the top of my file?

Comment: Please add a `fprintf(fptr,"ST_ID, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5\n");` before the `for` loop.