# Better way to write a csv in C with many variables and digit specifiers?

Tags: c, csv, formatting, printf

I currently have something like 13+ variables and 500,000 datapoints I'm outputting to a csv file, and I might add more outputs later since the project is in its early stages. The last fprintf line is huge.

```
int dig = 4;
    for(k = 0; k < cfg_ptr->nprt; k++){
        
        /*normalize output*/
        en_norm = en[k]*norm_factor;
        en0_norm = en0[k]*norm_factor;
        mu = rmu[k]*norm_factor;
        mu0 = rmu0[k]*norm_factor;

        fprintf(ofp,"%d,"\
        "%.*E,%.*E,%.*E,%.*E,%.*E,%.*E,%.*E,%.*E,%.*E,%.*E,%.*E,"\
        "%.*E,%.*E,%.*E,%.*E,%.*E,%.*E,%.*E,%.*E,%.*E,%.*E,%.*E\n"\
        otp[k],dig,\
        thet[k],dig,zet[k],dig,ptch[k],dig,pol[k],dig,rho[k],dig,mu,dig,en_norm,dig,rhol[k],dig,pphi[k],dig,xflr[k],dig,zflr[k],dig,\
        thet0[k],dig,zet0[k],dig,ptch0[k],dig,pol0[k],dig,rho0[k],dig,mu0,dig,en0_norm,dig,rhol0[k],dig,pphi0[k],dig,xflr0[k],dig,zflr0[k]);
    }
```

("dig" is the number of digits I want to output). I don't know if there's any way I can simplify typing this while being memory efficient. Some things I'm looking for specifically is not having to keep on repeating the "dig," or formatting a specific number of times the %.*E, repeats.

The solution I saw when looking this up was here

[Writing to a CSV file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916527/writing-to-a-csv-file-in-c)

which was exactly what I already did.

Comment: Separate it to several `fprintf`s...

Comment: Or, if the data is of the same type, create a union of a structure containing all of the data and an array. Then after populating the structure, print the array in a loop.

Comment: Yeah I originally did those two methods but reverted. I might try the multiple fprintf way again, but imo it looks more messy than the one I have right now.

I'll look into the union of structure. Thanks

Comment: I am sure it doesn't. Tracking which `%.*E` belongs to which parameter is way easier in small portions.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll look into the union of structure. I originally misread it as something else

Comment: Why are you outputting a selected number of digits? Are you trying to satisfy a certain format requirement or do you just want to record the true value in the file? If you want to record the true value, use `%a`. That outputs a hexadecimal floating-point format that includes enough information to reconstruct the exact value. Then you do not need `.*`. If you do not want hexadecimal, you can use `%.*g` and use `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` instead of `dig`, and then you will not need to change it to accommodate numbers with different scales or fraction parts.

Comment: You don't have to end lines with \ slash. It will just continue. And `"" ""` will merge themselves.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Just getting a selected number of digits. The actual values are like 20 digits long which I feel isn't necessary for the analysis I'm doing right now

Comment: Note that the trailing backslashes on the lines of the `printf()` statement are unnecessary.  Statements can be split across lines at any convenient point, such as after the comma separating two arguments in a function call.  The format string can be split and the compiler does "string concatenation" to combine consecutive string literals into a single string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

agreagate arrays into array of pointers, then you can have as many as you want arraysa to print.

```
int myprint(FILE *fo, double **data, size_t size, size_t index, int dig)
{
    int len = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        len += fprintf(fo, "%.*E%c", dig, data[i][index], i == size - 1 ? '\n' : ',');
    }
    return len;
}

double thet[100],zet[100],ptch[100],pol[100];
double *holder[] = {thet,zet,ptch,pol};

#define HS (sizeof(holder) / sizeof(holder[0]))

int main(void)
{
    for(size_t k = 0; k < 100; k++)
        myprint(stdout, holder, HS, k, 7);
}
```

Comment: Oh great - just wondering will that len += fprintf loop cause any overhead? I know stacking fprintf won't for most compilers. I don't know if adding in len will cause it to compile different though. And would you recommend leaving in the len or is it fine if I take it out?

Comment: it is not needed

Comment: Also, since all the data was originally stored in a struct, would it be possible to call them by doing *holder[] = {a->thet,b->zet}